# height not adding height to a empty div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys i am new to bootstrap and basically i have the following html ::

```
<div class="col-md-6 clients">

    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>


    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>

</div>
```

now after the 1st 3 col-xs-4 i want some vertical space , so i did the following :

```
<div class="col-md-6 clients">

    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>

    <div class="image-separator"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>

</div>
```

notice the div  `<div class="image-separator"></div>` and i gave it the following CSS :

```
.image-separator {
    height: 20px;
}
```

surprisingly no vertical space was create , so i played around a bit and added the following styles :

```
.image-separator {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

this did work , now why did jsut `height:20px` not work ? I am really curious and so i taught i would come here on SO and ask , can somebody please explain , i would love to learn how CSS works and so i am asking , new to CSS . [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fq6q4n7L/4/).

**NOTE::** I am not looking to solve this problem , its already solved , i am trying to understand why this happens !

Thank you.

Comment: The height works to me  - http://jsfiddle.net/fq6q4n7L/5/

Comment: It actually work but weird. In jsfiddle increase the height to e.g. 100px or 200px. But right now I also do not understand what happens there. I guess it is belonging to bootsrap. You should add that tag.

Comment: @sdcr very interesting height:100px works , height:40px does't work ! awesome lol

Comment: @Tenali_raman it's working here on Firefox.

Comment: here you can see what happened. http://jsfiddle.net/fq6q4n7L/6/ i will delete my answer.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel if you just want to add extra space below image, you could set margin-bottom to the image itself - http://jsfiddle.net/fq6q4n7L/9/ no drama.

Answer (score 3):

It didn't work before because bootstrap columns have a floating value: `float:left` and you have to clear that floating:

```
clear: both
```

Added to the css of your spacer

```
.image-separator {
    height: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
```

---

I'm editing this answer because I forgot to say that bootstrap has a class to clear floating elements much more eficiently: `clearfix`.

Comment: Oddly enough `clearfix` doesn't help - or at least not in the Fiddle.

Comment: @Press To use the ``clearfix`` class you have to add 2 elements, one for the clearfix and one for the spacer:  <div class="clearfix"></div><div class="image-separator"></div>. Or check it: http://jsfiddle.net/fq6q4n7L/10/

Answer (score 3):

It actually didn't work because you forgot to add div class=row before the div class="col-xs-4". See below

```
<div class="col-md-6 clients">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
      ...
    </div>

    <div class="image-separator"></div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your talking in bootstrap terminology  i want a CSS answer , thanks for the input , but i deliberatly did't add another row !

Comment: I am talking in bootstrap terminology, because that is what you are using. If you understood bootstrap then you would know that all col-xs-[num] has a float: left style. thus you HAVE to add float:left to your image-separator. Because all of the your images div are remove from the flow of the document. Take away the float:left from image-separator and put a border:1px solid black style instead and you will understand. So you need the row tag if you don't want to add the float:left! :)